# Find and Replace text format between keywords in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I tried to append upper case with space in notepad++, and it's work.

```
From:   GetTeamMemberByID
To: Get Team Member By ID
```

Search Criteria:

```
Find: (.)([A-Z]) 
Replace: \1 \2
```

But now I need to replace the format within specific keywords, how can I do?

e.g.Required keywords is "Description:" & "\r\n" in following sample:

From:

```
-- =============================================
--  Author: AP-1
--  Create date: 1/16/2014
--  Description:     GetTeamMemberByID
-- =============================================
```

To:

```
-- =============================================
--  Author: AP-1
--  Create date: 1/16/2014
--  Description:     Get Team Member By ID
-- =============================================
```

Thank you for your attention XD

Comment: Read more about [lookbehind](www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest this regex to replace only those within the `Description:`:

```
(?:Description:|(?!^)\G).*?[a-z]\K[A-Z]
```

And replace with  `$0`

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kU1wT4)

`(?:Description:|(?!^)\G)` matches `Description:` or at the end of the previous match.

`\K` will 'reset' the match so you don't have to put back what you matched previously.

Since `.` doesn't match newlines by default, you don't have to specify the ending `\r\n` 'keyword'.

The regex above works on N++ v6.5.2.

Comment: what is the `\G` doing can you please tell jerry dear

Comment: @aelor It's in my answer. "at the end of the previous match."

Comment: yes jerry its there but i was not able to get the meaning of it , sorry to sound so dumb. does that mean that the match will start from the first match again leaving the previous letters ? and wjat does $0 do

Comment: @aelor In the current problem, The first match is `Description: GetT`. `\G` makes the next match just after `T` so that it matches `eamM`  next. `$0` is the same as `\0` (the whole match).

Answer (score 1):

just for starters keeping your case in mind. I see that you have camel case present.

so you may check for that and replace accordingly as I have done here :

```
([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

replace with `\1 \2`

notice there is one blank space after `\1` and `\2`

example here : http://regex101.com/r/eF4vG0

Comment: @Alex yes I have written it assuming the match to be always camel case. If camel cases are repeated elsewhere the match will fail